# При нажатии на кнопку главного меню игра включается лишь на миг | PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, gui, pygame

Код на *python*, библиотека - *PyGame*
Написал главное меню, при нажатии на кнопку должен запускаться игровой цикл, но это происходит лишь на миг, помогите решить проблему, заранее благодарю
Картинки - https://yadi.sk/d/XkhfZTg79MBlow
Код:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

pygame.display.set_caption('Рыцарь')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("textures/icon.bmp"))

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_right.png'),
             pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_right2.png'),
             pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_right3.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_left.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_left2.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_left3.png')]
walkUp = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_up.png'),
          pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_up2.png'),
          pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_up3.png')]
walkDown = [pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_down.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_stand.png'),
            pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_down2.png')]

background = pygame.image.load('textures/first_karta.png')
playerStand = pygame.image.load('textures/Characters/pers_stand.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 1255
y = 675
width = 20
height = 40
speed = 5

right, left, up, down, animCount = False, False, False, False, 0

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)


def drawingWindow():
    global animCount
    win.blit(background, (0, 0))

    if animCount + 1 >= 60:
        animCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif up:
        win.blit(walkUp[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif down:
        win.blit(walkDown[animCount % 3], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()


def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, color)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)


click = False


def main_menu():
    while True:

        win.fill((0, 0, 0))
        draw_text('main menu', font, (255, 255, 255), win, 20, 20)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button_1 = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 200, 50)
        if button_1.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                drawingWindow()
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), button_1)

        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
        right, left, up, down = False, True, False, False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 1280 - width - 5:
        x += speed
        right, left, up, down = True, False, False, False
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5:
        y -= speed
        right, left, up, down = False, False, True, False
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 720 - height - 5:
        y += speed
        right, left, up, down = False, False, False, True
    else:
        right, left, up, down, animCount = False, False, False, False, 0

    main_menu()
    drawingWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

В твоём главном игровом цикле срабатывает ещё один цикл (в функции main_menu). Это совершенно необязательно.